# TypeScript React error: "Module not found: Can't resolve 'styled-components'"

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm, styled-components

After installing **@types/styled-components** package and compiling my Typescript React app I keep getting error:

> Module not found: Can't resolve 'styled-components'

I have dependancy in both package.json and package-lock.json and my import looks like this:

```
import styled from 'styled-components';
```

I even have the auto-completion when importing and yet after compiling, aforementioned error keeps popping up. 
What may be causing the problem and how to fix it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You just installed the types for the library, not the library itself. That explains the autocompletion as that comes from the type declaration files (`.d.ts`). You should run `npm i styled-components` as well.

Comment: Thanks, you’re right. I thought that @types contains whole library plus types.